# Twitter kit gives error despite successful login

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I am using Twitter kit to log in with Twitter. After I have been logged in into Twitter, I get the following error in log.

**Code to login:**

```
- (IBAction)btnTwitterLogin_pressed:(id)sender
{
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
     (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
         if (session) 
         {
             // This session is then used to make Twitter API requests.
             NSLog(@"%@", [session userID]);
             NSLog(@"%@", [session userName]);
             NSLog(@"%@", [session authToken]);
             NSLog(@"%@", [session authTokenSecret]);

             [self requestUserEmail];
         }
         else 
         {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];
}
```

**Error log:**

> [TwitterKit] didEncounterError:withMessage: Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: error

I couldn't find the reason. Have anyone faced the same issue ?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: No, I couldn't find anything, everything working fine but I still don't know why it shows that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the current version of Twitter Kit.